# Django/Python: how to know which tests cover a piece of code?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I know coverage python package is capable of creating reports (in html) that show if pieces of code are covered by tests, or not. I can also run just a single individual test, and know what does it covers.

Is there any way I can reverse the analysis? I mean, run all my tests, choose a line of code, and know which tests are hitting that line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of [coverage.py 5.0 alpha](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201810/who_tests_what_is_here.html).  There's a more recent alpha that the a3 mentioned in the blog post.  Give it a try and let me know how it works for you.